# Is $2^\omega=2^{\omega_1}$ consistent with $\text{cf}(2^\omega)>\omega$?

Tags: set-theory

I know that $2^\omega=2^{\omega_1}$ is consistent with ZFC.

This requires $2^\omega>\omega_1$, but of course this does not necessarily imply that $\text{cf}(2^\omega)>\omega$.

**Question.** Is $2^\omega=2^{\omega_1}$ consistent with $\text{cf}(2^\omega)>\omega$?

I don't see any reason why it wouldn't be.

PS. I want a simple YES or NO answer... no technical arguments required!

Comment: How did you figure that this requires that $\operatorname{cf}(2^\omega)>\omega_1$, but that does not imply that $\operatorname{cf}(2^\omega)>\omega$? I mean, $x>y$ and $y>z$---assuming $>$ is transitive---imply that $x>z$ as well.

Comment: @AsafKaragila They only said "this requires $2^\omega>\omega_1$."

Comment: @Noah: Maybe I read that sentence (in its entirety) differently...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, $2^\omega$ [always has uncountable cofinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig's_theorem_(set_theory)), so we don't need to do any work at all - it's not only possible, it's *necessary*. Similarly, $2^{\omega_1}$ always has cofinality $>\omega_1$, so if $2^{\omega}=2^{\omega_1}$ then this cardinal has cofinality $>\omega_1$.

---

More generally, if we make $2^\omega=2^\kappa$ for a large regular cardinal $\kappa$, then $2^\omega$ has cofinality at least $\kappa^+$, and moreover $2^\omega=2^\mu$ for all $\mu<\kappa$. And this is possible by (an easy special case of) [Easton's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easton's_theorem). In general, if you have a question about whether a certain phenomenon regarding the continuum function is possible, always consult Easton.

Incidentally, $2^\omega=2^{\omega_1}$ isn't too unnatural an assumption - e.g. it's a consequence of [the Proper Forcing Axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_forcing_axiom).

Comment: Your appeal to Easton is fine, but this was actually proved by Cohen in the OG forcing papers.

Comment: Not only PFA but already MA($\omega_1)$ implies this.